# Cython: Invalid use of fused types, type cannot be specialized

Tags: python, numpy, cython, cythonize

I have the following MCVE:

```
import numpy as np

cimport numpy as np
cimport cython

from cython cimport floating


def func1(floating[:] X_data, floating alpha):
    if floating is double:
        dtype = np.float64
    else:
        dtype = np.float32

    cdef floating[:] prios = np.empty(12, dtype=dtype)
    cdef int ws_size = 10

    C = np.argpartition(np.asarray(prios), ws_size)[:ws_size].astype(np.int32)

    cdef int res = func2(X_data, alpha, C)


cpdef int func2(floating[:] X_data, floating alpha, int[:] C):
    cdef int epoch = 1
    return epoch
```

Trying to run `cython test_fused.pyx` gives me:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
    cdef floating[:] prios = np.empty(12, dtype=dtype)
    cdef int ws_size = 10

    C = np.argpartition(np.asarray(prios), ws_size)[:ws_size].astype(np.int32)

    cdef int res = func2(X_data, alpha, C)
                       ^
------------------------------------------------------------

test_fused.pyx:21:24: no suitable method found

    Error compiling Cython file:
    ------------------------------------------------------------
    ...
        cdef floating[:] prios = np.empty(12, dtype=dtype)
        cdef int ws_size = 10

        C = np.argpartition(np.asarray(prios), ws_size)[:ws_size].astype(np.int32)

        cdef int res = func2(X_data, alpha, C)
                           ^
    ------------------------------------------------------------

    test_fused.pyx:21:24: no suitable method found

    Error compiling Cython file:
    ------------------------------------------------------------
    ...
        cdef floating[:] prios = np.empty(12, dtype=dtype)
        cdef int ws_size = 10

        C = np.argpartition(np.asarray(prios), ws_size)[:ws_size].astype(np.int32)

        cdef int res = func2(X_data, alpha, C)
                      ^
    ------------------------------------------------------------

    test_fused.pyx:21:19: Invalid use of fused types, type cannot be specialized

    Error compiling Cython file:
    ------------------------------------------------------------
    ...
        cdef floating[:] prios = np.empty(12, dtype=dtype)
        cdef int ws_size = 10

        C = np.argpartition(np.asarray(prios), ws_size)[:ws_size].astype(np.int32)

        cdef int res = func2(X_data, alpha, C)
                      ^
    ------------------------------------------------------------

    test_fused.pyx:21:19: Invalid use of fused types, type cannot be specialized
```

I had a more complicated code which also passed the array `C` as a runtime defined value, which did not cause any issue. What is the cause of this compilation error?

I am puzzled, because slight modifications (adding a dummy keyword arg to `func1` and two keyword args to `func2`) make the code compile:

```
def func1(floating[:] X_data, floating alpha,
          int dummy_variable=1):  # added dummy_variable here

    # same as before here

    cdef int res = func2(X_data, alpha, C,
                       dummy_variable=dummy_variable)


cpdef int func2(floating[:] X_data, floating alpha, int[:] C, 
    int K=6, int dummy_variable=1):  # added K and dummy variable here

    cdef int epoch = 1
    return epoch
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start with a smaller reproducer:

```
%%cython
import numpy as np
from cython cimport floating

def func1(floating[:] X_data):
    C = np.empty(12, dtype=np.int_32)
    func2(X_data, C)

cpdef func2(floating[:] X_data, int[:] C):
    pass
```

It doesn't compile.

One important observation: `func2` is a `cpdef`, that means Cython will call it as a raw-C-function from `func1`. These two C-signatures will be produced by Cython for fused `func2` function (one for `double` and one for `float`):

```
static PyObject *__pyx_fuse_0__pyx_f_4test_func2(__Pyx_memviewslice, __Pyx_memviewslice, int __pyx_skip_dispatch); /*proto*/
static PyObject *__pyx_fuse_1__pyx_f_4test_func2(__Pyx_memviewslice, __Pyx_memviewslice, int __pyx_skip_dispatch); /*proto*/
```

So `C` is expected to be a `__Pyx_memviewslice`, but as long as Cython is concerned it is a `PyObject` in `func1`, so there is no way the function can be called as `cdef`. What I don't understand: why doesn't Cython fall back to python-`def` version?

The C signature is a little bit misleading and Cython does more type checking during the compilation, so it would not help to define  `C` as

```
cdef float[:] C
```

because even if `C` is in this case also a `__Pyx_memviewslice` it doesn't have the right type, and only

```
cdef int[:] C
```

would work.

If `func2` were defined as

```
cpdef func2(floating[:] X_data, C):
```

the corresponding two C-signatures would be

```
static PyObject *__pyx_fuse_0__pyx_f_4test_func2(__Pyx_memviewslice, PyObject *, int __pyx_skip_dispatch); /*proto*/
static PyObject *__pyx_fuse_1__pyx_f_4test_func2(__Pyx_memviewslice, PyObject *, int __pyx_skip_dispatch); /*proto*/
```

so it is possible to pass `C`, which is a `PyObject` to these function.

So there are twos way to solve the compilation issue:

- use `cdef int[:] C` in `func1`, or
- drop `int[:] C` in the signature of `func2`

---

So why does adding a dummy-parameter, i.e.

```
%%cython -a
import numpy as np
from cython cimport floating

def func1(floating[:] X_data, int dummy_variable=1):
    C = np.empty(12, dtype=np.int_32)
    func2(X_data, C, dummy_variable=dummy_variable)

cpdef func2(floating[:] X_data, int[:] C, int k=6, dummy_variable = 1):
    pass
```

works?

Actually there is a third way to make the code compile: by making `func2` a python-only `def`-function. In this case, the type of `C` doesn't play a role during the compile time and will be checked at run time.

The thing is: the case with your dummy-variables, Cython decides to call `func2` as a Python-function and not as C-function, and thus the type mismatch doesn't play a role.

You can easily see that by inspecting the annotated html-file.

However, I cannot say, what is the reason for Cython to fall back to a Python-function-call for your work-around. All I can tell: don't providing a value for `k` plays a important role.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't cdef C because it's redefined at each iteration inside a for loop. But I'll try to remove the int[:] before C. My main question is: what makes it work in the last snippet I posted?

Comment: You should be able to cdef C. Put the `cdef int[:] C` at the top level near the start of the function, and `C = whatever` inside the loop. The definition and assignment don't need to be in the same place. (I don't know about the last snippet - I think this whole thing looks like a Cython bug, and should probably be reported at https://github.com/cython/cython/issues)

Comment: @P.Camilleri I tried to give a more concise answer, hopefully it will help you.

Comment: @DavidW I did some further analysis and somehow it makes at least some sense. What I'm not sure about, why Cython doesn't fall back to python-call, when it is not possible to call `func2` as `cdef`, that might be a bug.

Comment: @ead OK, now I think I can follow what's happened - it's the attempt to resolve the call at compile time as if with `cdef` that's important. I'm not completely convinced it's desired behaviour, since a function with no fused type but a memoryview `cdef f(int[:])` get compiled with a runtime error if the type doesn't match. It seems to be that the fused type _shouldn't_ change that (but does)