# Cython function pointer with fused type input: Invalid use of fused types, type cannot be specialized

Tags: python, cython, static-typing

Differ from earlier [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51083070/cython-invalid-use-of-fused-types-type-cannot-be-specialized), I work with all cdef function here. If I work with function pointer of fused_type input, it will raise "Invalid use of fused types, type cannot be specialized". On the contrary, the function pointer with built-in type works well. Why?

```
cimport cython


# raise error
ctypedef fused fused_type:
   float
   int

ctypedef fused_type (* _func_pointer) (fused_type[:])

cdef fused_type base_func(fused_type[:] arg1):
   return arg1[0]

cdef fused_type c_entry(fused_type[:] arg1, _func_pointer func):
   return func(arg1)

cdef fused_type base_wrapper(fused_type[:] arg1):
   return c_entry(arg1, base_func)

""" -------   """
# works
cdef int base_func(int[:] arg1):
   return arg1[0]

cdef int c_entry(int[:] arg1, _func_pointer func):
   return func(arg1)

cdef int base_wrapper(int[:] arg1):
   return c_entry(arg1, base_func)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change it to

```
cdef fused_type base_wrapper(fused_type[:] arg1):
   return c_entry(arg1, base_func[fused_type])
```

When `base_wrapper` is specialized, that selects the specialization of `base_func` for whatever `fused_type` currently is in `base_wrapper`.

---

The rough explanation of why:

```
ctypedef fused_type (* _func_pointer) (fused_type[:])
```

This doesn't define a function pointer type that takes and returns `fused_type`. Instead it defines a fused type with containing two types:

```
float (*)(float[:])
int (*)(int[:])
```

When you do `base_func` on its own it isn't a "real" function - you get one of the specializations either by calling it, or my manually selecting it (e.g. `base_func[int]`).

Therefore in `base_wrapper` the line `return c_entry(arg1, base_func)` doesn't know which specialization of `base_func` it should be using, and therefore can't pick which of the two types of `_func_pointer` it should match.

The Cython fused type system is fairly dump and doesn't make too much of an effort to resolve confusion - it's either an unambiguous exact match or no match at all.